# Android Global KeyListener necessary?

Tags: java, android, global, keylistener

I want my app to start, after the back button was pressed 3Times. 
So I created this class which is executed in the Launcher.

```
 public class KeyManager extends Activity {

    @Override
   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
       if(KeyEvent == "Back key"){
             Log.e("KM", "PRESSED!!!!!"+keyCode);
       }

       //return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
       return false; 
   }
```

}

This code works, if it s implemented in the launcher class, but it does not work, if the app is in the background. How or which key listener do I need for listening to background keys or more if the app is working only in the background?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible due security reasons. It's more likely a keylogger. If you really want to do that use an AccessibilityService which let you capture the KeyHooks even on a non-rooted Device. Warning: This is Dangerous and user must explizit enable it, to get it activated.

You may/can also modify the default keyboard, to capture those.

Comment: The BACK button is not on a keyboard.

Comment: The BackButton is a Key like all others. It's KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK.

Comment: Yes, but the BACK button is not implemented on soft keyboards. It is part of the navigation bar. While there is nothing stopping somebody from creating a soft keyboard that contains a BACK button, that will be a *duplicate* of the navigation bar's BACK button. Moreover, a soft keyboard will only appear where user input is requested.

Answer (score 0):

> I want my app to start, after the back button was pressed 3Times.

You are welcome to download the Android source code, alter the operating system to contain this feature, compile it into a ROM mod, and install that ROM mod on your device.

Otherwise, what you want is not supported by Android.